# how to determine if a String starts with a specific character?

Tags: java

Is there a built in method in Java to determine if a String starts with a specific character? How can I write, to an output file, only the lines that do not start with a defined character?

```
   try {
        File input = new File("input");
        File output = new File("output");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            printer.write(s);
        }
        printer.flush();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found. Please scan in new file.");
    }
```

Comment: You have a String, so your question is really how to know whether a String starts with a certain character. (The fact that you're reading and writing to a file is immaterial.) As the answers below show, once you know how to do that, you just put it in an `if()` statement. With a question like this, your first port of call is Javadoc for `java.lang.String`.

Comment: I have also edited the question to reflect his problem better. Also the grammar is better. I agree with Andrew Spencer, I think the OP thought the problem was somewhere else (and had something to do with writing/reading to/from files).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

Built in a check if the character is there.

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    if (s.startsWith("?"))
        printer.write(s);
}
```

Or

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    char c = s.charAt(0);
    if (c.matches('?'))
        printer.write(s);
}
```

EDIT: Based on your comment:

```
int i;
char c;
String s;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    s = sc.nextLine();
    c = ' ';
    i = 0;
    while (c.matches(' ')) {
        c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c.matches('?'))
            printer.write(s);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Not sure if the code works, I'm currently unable to test the code. But you might get the idea.

Comment: okay thanks, but what if there are also EMPTY SPACES at the beginning of line, then how i can say to exclude empty room and begin checking where characters start?

Comment: says at c= " "; required char, found string.

Comment: Come on, you can try something for yourself can't you? Look up how to set a char-value and see what is going wrong... To be honest, I think you are just being lazy now... Replace the `"` by a `'`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check for text before writing in your while loop.

```
 if(check your string)
   printer.write(s);
```